# Problema función python3

Tags: python-3.x, funciones, terminal

Tengo un problema con Python y una función, el problema es que al escribir el siguiente código no funciona dentro de una función, en cambio quito la función y me funciona

[image: Codigo principal]

Ni siquiera funciona el print ni puedo imprimir nada, ni texto sale en pantalla, tampoco me sale un error:

[image: No da ningun error]

No funciona nada dentro de la función ni con return ni nada no sé por qué, pero si la quito, sí funciona todo, ¿alguien me puede ayudar? gracias.

Comment: Hola recemi, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Agrega siempre el código y errores como texto, nunca como imágenes. En cuanto a tu problema, ¿llamas en algún momento a la función con `hola()`? Porque si no lógicamente nada se ejecuta.... Agrega la linea `hola()` al final de todo al mismo nivel de identación que `def hola():`,  no dentro de la función.

Comment: Hola, gracias me ha servido tu respuesta, ya lo he solucionado

Comment: Lo que dice @FJSevilla es correcto para que puedas ejecutarlo desde la terminal. Sé que la pregunta requiere cumplir con los requisitos de que no sea imagen el código, pero creo que vale la pena explicar como se puede ejecutar desde la terminal este tipo de funciones.

Answer (score 1):

### Fichero

Asumamos que se tiene el fichero `hola.py` en él se encuentran las siguientes funciones:

```
def hola_funcion(): print("Hola Mundo"); return

def sumar(a,b): print(a+b); return

restar = lambda a, b: a-b # similar a def restar(a,b): return a-b
```

### Terminal

Si quieres ejecutar la function `hola_function` del fichero `hola.py` desde la terminal tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
# El símbolo `$` o `%` al inicio es una formalidad que
# indica que la sentencia se está ejecutando en un terminal

$ python3 -c "from hola import hola_funcion; hola_funcion()"
# se imprime en consola: $ Hola Mundo
```

Similar con la función `restar` pero esta no tiene `print`:

```
$ python3 -c "from hola import restar; print(restar(7,4))"  
# se imprime en consola: $ 3
```

O también puedes llamar las tres funciones `from hola import *`:

```
$ python3 -c "from hola import *; sumar(11,9); hola_funcion(); print(restar(5,2))" 
# se imprime en consola: $ 20
# se imprime en consola: $ Hola Mundo
# se imprime en consola: $ 3
```

### UTF-8

Quizás una desventaja es cuando tienes caracteres especiales Unicode/UTF-8 y debes imprimir en el terminal.

Afortunadamente se cuenta con `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` para lo anterior

```
def spanish(): return "¡cigüeña! : aquí se habla español" # en el fichero hola.py
```

En el terminal:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python3 -c "from hola import spanish; print(spanish())"
# se imprime en consola: $ ¡cigüeña! : aquí se habla español
```